# Does the median make angles in the same proportion as the sides?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Till I remember I had studied this in the lower classes, but am not sure whether this is true or not.
In the figure CD is a median.
Does CD divide the angles 1 and 2 in the same ratio of the sides a and b?

=> Is m(1)/m(2) = a/b

[image]

Comment: measure angle(1)/measure angle(2)=a/b , is correct.

Comment: Are the angles measured in radians or degrees? Either way, although I haven't worked out the details, I think it may be false. What you might have been looking is for the related angle bisector theorem (google).

Answer (score 1):

No, not true at all.

For example, let AD = DB = 1, and let CD = 0.1.  By the triangle inequality, we must have 0.9 < a < 1.1 and 0.9 < b < 1.1, which leads to 9/11 < a/b < 11/9.  The ratios of the angles can be any positive number.  Clearly, they can't always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

For an easily computed counterexample, take $\angle A$ to be a right angle, take $|AB|=2$, and $b=1$.  Then $\angle 2 = 45^\circ$ and $\angle 1 = 135^\circ$, so $\angle 1/\angle 2 = 3$, but $a/b = \sqrt5$.

As mentioned in a comment, you might be thinking of the [angle bisector theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).